# Javascript- accessing properties with dot operator or bracket notation whats the difference?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Is their any difference on accessing object properties with the dot operator then accessing them with the bracket notation? example.

```
var objects={
"name":"john",
"age":23,
"friends":["mike","harry"]
};
document.write(objects["friends"]);
```

prints out exactly what this would

```
var objects={
"name":"john",
"age":23,
"friends":["mike","harry"]
};
document.write(objects.friends);
```

in the learning stage and curious if their is more to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var person = {
"first name": "Mad",
"last name": "Max",
};

console.log(person["first name"], person["last name"]);
```

There is no difference between accessing properties using the dot operator or via string name.

That being said, where the string name accessing comes in handy is a case as follows:

Say if you have an object person with properties: first name, last name.

```
person = {
"first name": "Mad",
"last name": "Max",
}
```

Now you can access `person["first name"]` and `person["last name"]`

So here you can include spaces and any other otherwise invalid property names that are to be accessed via dot operator.

Answer (score 0):

functionality wise there is no difference,
 but object["property'] gives you functionality to pass property name as a parameter, while in case of object.Property you can not pass property name..